# Number of NxN grids with only one "spot" allowed

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I'm working on a question where a spot is defined as "A 1 × 1 blue square that shares an edge with a red square to its left or above it". The square being in some NxN grid with all squares being either blue or red.

The question is asking how many grids are there with one and only one spot in it. An earlier part of the question was to get how many grids have no spots which I just did by adding them up but I'm looking for the method for how to actually solve this second part, rather than trying to count them all up

EDIT: Formula for Mike  (2(N!))/(N!*N!) or 10C5

Comment: Please edit your question to show your work for the "no spots" version (on this site, work is expected to be shown, not just a bare question).

Comment: In the grids you are counting, is _every_ square colored red or blue? Or are the squares either red, blue, or uncolored? The question as stated is unclear, please _edit_ it to clarify.

Comment: @MikeEarnest The squares indeed seem to be specified as being only red or blue. From the first para of the question - "all squares being either blue or red".

Comment: @DevashsihKaushik Wow, it really was right there, I was being a jerk then. Apologies, Galbotrix! Still, it would be helpful to edit in your efforts for the zero-spot case, so we can cater an answer relevant to what you know.

Comment: @MikeEarnest  I didn't post the work cause I only "solved" it by adding up all the possible combinations of no spots https://imgur.com/a/IiKXalK . Thats why I'm looking for how to solve part two mathematically.

Comment: @quasi See above, it wouldn't let me tag two people at once

Comment: @Galbotrix: Where is the problem from? Is it from a book? If so, which one?

Comment: @quasi https://imgur.com/2ZXHbZ2 Here's the question that the lecturer said to try but I don't know how to do it without just adding all the combinations which isn't as feasible for the second part

Comment: @Galbotrix You should solve the zero-spot case for general $N$ first, as the one-spot case is harder. Hint for that: in a zero-spot grid, the border between the blue and red will be a path from the lower left corner to the upper right. There is a nice formula for the number of such paths in an $N\times N$ grid, what is it? This is a classic beginner combinatorics problem When you know, please _edit that into your post_. Once you do, I will happily give guidance for the one-spot case.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you for that, much faster way than just adding them like I was, thank you, didn't see that the border could be used as a line like that, I was looking at just the blue squares. Could you give me the start/tip for the one-spot case so I could work on it?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I worked on your tip and replied to it, just replying here because I don't know if that notifies you or not

Comment: @Galbotrix: Question: If a blue cell has both a red cell directly to the left _and_ a red cell directly above, does that blue cell qualify as a spot?

Comment: @quasi it only counts as a spot if it has one or the other I believe, if it has both it's not a spot

Comment: @Galbotrix:  In math and logic, unless specifed otherwise, or unless the context mandates otherwise, by default, "or" means "inclusive or".

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

First, count the number of grids with a single "horizontal spot," i.e. a blue square with a red square to its left. At the end, multiply by two.

Suppose the red square is in row $r$ and column $c$. An example when $n=7, r=3, c=5$ is below. Note that placing the spot at row $r$ and column $c$ forces a lot of other entries to be red and blue in order to prevent any further spots. However, there are still two subgrids left to be filled, which are smaller instances of the zero-spot column. This lets you solve the problem for any particular $r,c$, and then you can sum over all possible values of $r, c$. The summations will simplify nicely if you group the terms together correctly.

```
        v
B B B B B B .
B B B B B B .
. . . . R B . <-
. . . . R R R
. . . . R R R
. . . . R R R
. . . . R R R
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/JcIYvr3 @MikeEarnest Does this work as a general solution for one spot cases? I have some rough work in too

Comment: In your image, the two binomial coefficients should be multiplied together, not added. You know, when I roughly thought this problem out in my head, I though that that summation would simplify nicely, but I am not so sure now. I will keep thinking about it.

Comment: @Mike Earnest:  If you mutliply by $2$, don't you have to adjust for the count of those grids where the "spot" has both a red cell directly to the left and a red cell directly above?

Comment: @quasi I was assuming the "or" in the definition of spot was exclusive. I think inclusive or make the problem much harder, and it is hard enough already...

Comment: @Mike Earnest: But doesn't the approach you suggested in the comments for the zero-spot case assume inclusive "or"?

Comment: @quasi Good point! OK, I am just wrong. I guess I was thinking of a spot as a pair of squares, so that a blue square with a red square to its west and to its north would count as two spots, and therefore not be counted for the one spot case.